# General equation of the line through the endpoints - derivation as value of "y"

Tags: linear-algebra

could you please tell me how this equation

$y={\frac {y_{1}-y_{0}}{x_{1}-x_{0}}}(x-x_{0})+y_{0}.$

was derived from "general equation of the line through the endpoints" below?

${\frac {y-y_{0}}{y_{1}-y_{0}}}={\frac {x-x_{0}}{x_{1}-x_{0}}}.$

I was just reading about[Bresenham's line algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and came across this in the "Method" section of the article.

I've only started learning math and would be very grateful to see the steps to derive one from the other. Thank you.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(y_1-y_0)$ then add $y_0$ to both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first lets go over how we got $\frac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$
Well, we know that the slope of the line from any two points must be the same.

So using this, we can say $\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{y1-y0}{x1-x0}$, which we get from the slope formula. $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ are set points on the graph, while $(x,y)$ is any point on the graph.

We rearrange this to get the first equation we talk about $\frac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$, and then we do algebraic manipulation to solve for y.

These are the steps:
$\frac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$
multiply both sides by $y_1-y_0$
$(y-y_0)=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}(y_1-y_0)$
since the order of multiplication and division does not matter, we can go ahead and write it as
$(y-y_0)=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0)$
now the last step to isolate y is to add y0 to both sides
$y=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0)+y_0$
and this is what they got :)

Hope this helped!!

Comment: More than helpful! Thank you.